# pro-p dense subgroup in the free group

Tags: gr.group-theory, profinite-groups, free-groups

Let $G_p$ be pseudovariety of all finite $p$-group. The pro-$p$ topology on a group $G$ is the unique group topology such that the set of normal subgroups $N$ with $G/N$ in $G_p$ is a fundamental system of neighborhoods of the identity.

Margolis, Sapir and Weil showed that if a finitely generated subgroup $H$ of the free group  is $G_p$-dense  then $H$ contains a subgroup of rank $n$(=rank of free group) which is $G_p$-dense. In the proof of theorem 6.1, in "Dynamics of implicit operations and tameness of pseudovarieties ", Jorge Almeida used this fact in every extension closed pseudovarieties. I can not proof this and I think this not true. I appreciate any proof or counter example

Comment: I expect "$G_p$-dense" means "dense in the pro-$p$ topology? and that the generalization means the same fact when the pro-$p$ topology is replaced with the pro-$V$ topology when $V$ is an extension-closed pseudo variety of finite groups?

Comment: @YCor, this is surely what the op meant